# How to fix recommendations Failing on SetFetchSize() with Mahout

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mahout

I have a functioning recommender that I wanted to make faster so I decided to connect it directly to my database.  However, every time I try to recommend things to people I get an error that `setFetchSize() is not >=0`.  Here is my code:

```
MySQLJDBCDataModel dataModel = null;
try {
  Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource ds = new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource();
  ds.setServerName("xxxxx");
  ds.setDatabaseName("xxxxx");
  ds.setUser("xxxxx");
  ds.setPassword(xxxxx);
  ds.setDomain("xxxxx");
  //net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.setFetchSize(10);
  dataModel = new MySQLJDBCDataModel(ds, "test_tbl", "user_id", "item_id", "preference", null);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("can't connect");
}
ArrayList<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();
ItemSimilarity similarity = new FileItemSimilarity(new File("output/part-r-00000"));
ItemBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericItemBasedRecommender(dataModel, similarity);
//List<RecommendedItem> recommendedItems=recommender.recommend(userid,10);
Recommender cachingRecommender = new CachingRecommender(recommender);
List<userRecData> allUserRecs = new ArrayList<userRecData>();
List<RecommendedItem> uRec=cachingRecommender.recommend(userobjectid,10);
```

***And I get the error:***

```
java.sql.SQLException: The setFetchSize method requires a parameter value >= 0.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.setFetchSize(JtdsStatement.java:998)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.AbstractJDBCDataModel.getNumThings(AbstractJDBCDataModel.java:584)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.AbstractJDBCDataModel.getNumUsers(AbstractJDBCDataModel.java:560)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.CachingRecommender.<init>(CachingRecommender.java:63)
at mia.recommender.RecommenderIntro.getRecommendations(RecommenderIntro.java:79)
at mia.recommender.RecommenderIntro.main(RecommenderIntro.java:43)
```

It fails on the `cachingRecommender`, or if I take that out, on `recommnder.recommend`
I thought that Mahout automatically set the fetch size to `1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `MySQLJDBCDataModel`, but your database is SQL Server. The MySQL implementation disables fetch size with a negative value because its driver needs that. You need to customize AbstractJDBCDataModel to work with SQL Server -- by not overriding `getFetchSize()` for example.